# How to perform single Struts Form Submit action

Tags: javascript, html, struts

I have Multiple button in single html form , but i need to perform only single button action other button do not go to execute() method in struts 1.3

Eg:

```
button1: connect
button2 : disconnect 
button3 :save
```

i need to perform only save button action will go to the struts execute() method others won't go

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make Button1 and Button2 as simple button and make button3 as submit button

```
<button type="button" onclick="connect()">Button1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="disconnect()">Button2</button>

<input type="submit" value="button3">
```

Answer (score 1):

first two are normal buttons nd hence click those buttons dont submit the form to server until u write the onclick() event, but 3rd one is submit buttton by click on submit request send to server automayically to the resource given in action attribute in  tag.

```
<input type="button" value="connect"/>
<input type="button" value="disconnect"/>
<input type="submit" value="save"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend your action DispatchAction and create 3 different methods for each button http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/struts-extras/apidocs/org/apache/struts/actions/DispatchAction.html
**OR**
Use `<input type="button">` for first 2 buttons and `submit` for button3.